# is word embedding in Keras a dimensionality reduction technique also?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nlp, word-embedding

I wanted to understand the purpose of `embedding_dim` vs using a one hot vector of the entire `vocab_size`, Is it a dimension reduction to the one hot vector from `vocab_size` dim to `embedding_dim` dimensions or is there any other utility intuitively? Also how should one decide the `embedding_dim` number?

Code -

```
    vocab_size = 10000
    embedding_dim = 16
    max_length = 120
    
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_length=max_length),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    ])
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()
```

O/P -

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding (Embedding)        (None, 120, 16)           160000    
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 1920)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 6)                 11526     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 7         
=================================================================
Total params: 171,533
Trainable params: 171,533
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a small number of categorical features and less training data you have to use a one-hot encoding. If you have large training data and a large number of categorical features you have to use embeddings.

**Why were Embeddings developed?**
If you have a large number of categorical features and you used one-hot encoding you will end up getting a huge sparse matrix with most of the elements as zero. This is not suitable for training ML models. Your data will suffer from the curse of dimensionality. With embeddings, you can essentially represent a large number of categorical features using a smaller dimension. Also, the output is a dense vector rather than a sparse vector.

**Drawbacks of embeddings:**

- Requires time to train
- Requires a large amount of training data

**Advantage**

- Embeddings can tell you about the semantics of items. It groups related items close together. This is not the case with one-hot encoding. One-hot encoding is just an orthogonal representation of an item in another dimension.

**What size to select for embedding vector.**

```
embedding_dimensions =  vocab_size ** 0.25
```

You can see [here](https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/11/introducing-tensorflow-feature-columns.html).

**Note:** This is just a thumb rule. You can select embedding dimensions smaller or greater than this. The quality of word embedding increases with higher dimensionality. But after reaching some point, the marginal gain will diminish.

Comment: Very nicely explained! Thank you!

Comment: Just one followup question on the same, what impacts does increasing embedding_dim #s have apart from time?

Comment: The more embedding dimensions you give the more high-quality embeddings you produce. But will require more training data as well as more number of categorical features.

Comment: But the curse of dimensionality then starts coming in there too right? Say if my vocab_size is 100 and I create a embedding with 50 dimensions, also can this result in overfitting?

Comment: Yes, you can use the thumb rule to approximate the embedding dimensions. That said it all boils down to one question and that is `what works best for my problem/dataset`. Using 50 dimensions to represent vocab of size 100 is overkill. It's like representing a point(x,y) in a 10-dimensional plane.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks for the answer! However, don't you feel sarcasm datasets generally would need a higher dimensional space for dealing with the ambiguity. Ik that 50 is an overkill but if datasets are extremely ambiguous then we should go for a higher dim count. That being said, thanks for the explanation!